# NGINX Ingress Controller - Rewrite Swagger index.html to root domain

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, swagger, nginx-ingress, swashbuckle

I have a .NET 7 api project deployed into Kubernetes running the Kubernetes Ingress-NGINX Controller with the following Ingress definition:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: api
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      location = / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
      }
      
      location = @htmlext {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
      }
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.domain.com
  rules:
    - host: api.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: api
                port:
                  name: http-port
```

The .NET API exposes Swagger UI on `https://api.domain.com/index.html` and the Swagger API endpoint is set up like so:

```
app.UseSwagger(o =>
{
    o.RouteTemplate = "{documentName}/api.json";
});

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/api.json", "API v1");

    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

What I would like to achieve is to have the Swagger UI `https://api.domain.com/index.html` be shown at the root URL: `https://api.domain.com` (without the index.html). All other routes hitting the Ingress should function as normal since the API is served at `https://api.domain.com/v1/<endpoint>` etc

I have tried a whole heap of combinations of NGINX Ingress annotations for both `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` and `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet`. For example:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      location = / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
      }
      
      location = @htmlext {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
      }

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(.*/)index\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 last;
      rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 last;
```

But I just cant seem to get it working. I get either an infinite redirect loop or NGINX throws a 500 error.

Is this actually possible?

**Update:**

After trying the set of NGINX Ingress annotations as suggested in the comment by Kranthiveer Dontineni, the URL rewrite seems to work but then Swagger UI displays this error:

[image: Swagger UI error]

Interestingly, I can navigate to the Swagger doc definition at `https://api.domain.com/v1/api.json` and the JSON document does indeed specify a version tag so not sure what the issue is?

Comment: Can you try the following config and let us know the result: 

`annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^/$ /index.html last;
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
      location = / {
        rewrite ^ /index.html;
      } `

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Thanks! I've tried that and the rewrite seems to work but I now get a Swagger error? (Please see post with updated info and image of error message)

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Also, if I manually navigate to https://api.domain.com/index.html it doesn't rewrite back to the root https://api.domain.com Is it possible to add this rewrite rule in as well please?

Comment: Hi Can you provide the `api.json` file... and we can achieve the second redirection as well, let me try that..